# On questions such as "How do you know that X doesn't work? Have you tried it all possible ways?"

Tags: fallacies

I often find people using questions similar to the following one:

> How do you know there isn't a god? Have you looked everywhere?

As the answer to the second question is obviously "no", this seems to generate an unjustified willingness to accept that there is reason to accept that god exists. Sometimes, the question is made in more mundane subjects:

> How do you know that X doesn't work? Have you tried it all possible ways?

And the effect seems to be the same I previously described. It seems that there is an "infinite potentiality" and an unjustified belief that this yields a confirmation for something. I speculate this is a fallacy, if so is there a name to it?

Comment: It is called [shifting the burden of proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance) and relies on *ad ignorantiam* fallacy, [God of the gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_of_the_gaps) is a more specialized form of it. The most effective response is probably a counteranalogy due to Russell:"How do you know that there isn't a teapot orbiting Jupiter? Did you travel to space and look?" Claims need to be credible at least on their face before one is entitled to ask for evidence that justifies disbelieving them.

Comment: That you don't know that X doesn't work is a fact, that is not the error in the argument. The error is (also) a false dichotomy. Suppose the example is someone reporting a software bug, but the developer not being able to replicate it. Does the bug not exist or does the bug report not include all relevant information? Do you really know the bug doesn't exist if you can't reproduce? You wouldn't claim that, you would say the reporter needs to provide more information. Lack of proof is not proof of lack (or however that saying goes). This goes of course in both directions.

Comment: @kutschkem Yes but given a reasonable amount of searching, it's reasonable to assume that. Suppose you lose your driver's licence and you will need it in a few days, this generates a lot of propositions: (1) It could have been destroyed; (2) It could have been dumped in the sea by someone; (3) It could have been buried somewhere; etc. Do you (1) keep endlessly searching for its remains? (2) Initiate an expensive sea expedition to verify the entire ocean? (3) Dig holes everywhere in the planet to look up for it?, etc.

Comment: @BillyRubina No but that's not the point, right? The fact is that I lost the drivers license. I can prioritize where to look according to 1) prior likelyhood of it being somewhere, 2) time it takes to verify it being there. If it got thrown in the trash and already driven to some dump, it might as well be at the bottom of the sea, it might not be completely unrecoverable but it will be faster to get a new one than to recover the old one.

Comment: @BillyRubina The key part is slightly different from God's existence, in that I COULD theoretically, look everywhere and as such decide, in the sense of [decidability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)) the location of the key. With God, I can only semi-decide: One possible way is If I pray to God and ask whether he is there, and he reveals himself to me, then he exists. But I have no way of deciding that God does not exist, even if I "looked everywhere". So the question "Have you looked everywhere?" is flawed.